# How does teacher get first step?

Tags: trigonometry

Below are the steps the teacher took to solve:

$y = \sqrt{3}\sin x + \cos x$ find min and max on $[0, 2\pi)$

Step 1: = $2\sin(x + \pi/6))$

How does the teacher get this first step?

Note: No calculus please.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm posting this answer in response to the comment thread under picakhu's answer; writing comments was getting a bit tedious.  The answer has the same content as Isaac's, but is explained a little differently, which might be useful for the OP.

The general problem, of which this is a special case, is:

Given an expression of the form  $a \sin x + b \cos x$, for some numbers $a$ and $b$, to rewrite it in the form $c \sin (x + \theta)$, for some appropriate choice 
of $c$ and $\theta$ (which will be related to $a$ and $b$ in some way, of course --- and we have to find out what that way is!).

Suppose first that $a^2 + b^2 = 1$.  Then trigonometry (especially the point of view of the unit circle) tells us that there is an angle $\theta$ such
that $a = \cos \theta$ and $b = \sin \theta$.

Thus we can write $a \sin x + b \cos x = \cos \theta \sin x + \sin \theta \cos x,$ and via the addition theorem for $\sin$, we recognize this as being $\sin(x + \theta).$

Now in most examples, it may not be that $a^2 + b^2 = 1$.  But it equals something (!), so let's call that something $c^2$.  Then we see
that $(a/c)^2 + (b/c)^2 = 1$, so we can choose $\theta$ so that
$a/c = \cos \theta$ and $b/c = \sin \theta$.  Then as above
we find that $(a/c)\sin x + (b/c) \cos x = \sin (x + \theta),$
and so (finishing finally) we have
$$a \sin x + b \cos x = c \sin (x + \theta).$$

In the OP's example, $a = \sqrt{3}$ and $b = 1$, so $c = 2$,
and we are led to the given answer.

Note that in practice this whole process will be easiest when $a/c$ and $b/c$ are easily recognized trig function special values, like $1/2$ or $\sqrt{2}/2$ or $\sqrt{3}/2$.  If they are just somewhat random numbers, then you won't be able to figure out the correct choice of $\theta$ without using a calculator to
compute $\theta$.

Comment: Your answer is easier for me to follow.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of telling you how your teacher got that, try doing the opposite and expand out $\sin(a+b)=\sin(a)\cos(b)+\cos(a)\sin(b)$

The rest should be trivial

Comment: I need a little more info than that.  There is no a and b in the problem above, so I am confused.

Comment: @subt13: The policy of the site is to not give full answers to homework questions, so pikachu has done what he should. This is a pretty good hint. The only other thing I would say is "equate coefficients". That should lead you there pretty quickly.

Comment: @subt13: Dear subt13, You have to choose some particular $a$ and $b$.  Do you see any similarities between $\sin(a+b)$ and $\sin(x + \pi/6).$

Comment: @Noldorin - I understand the policy, I actually have all of the steps to the answer, I just don't understand it.  I'm not even taking a math class...

Comment: @picakhu: Dear picakhu, I think the formula is $\sin(a+ b) = \sin a \cos b + \cos a \sin b.$  Regards,

Comment: You'll have to be more specific about what you don't understand then..

Comment: @Matt: I see.  So the teacher was just trying with $\pi/6$ as a starting point?

Comment: @subt13: Dear subt13, Yes.  When faced with an expression of the form something $\times \sin x +$ something else $\times \cos x$, you can always massage it to be of the form something $\times \sin (x + \text{ some angle})$.  In your particular case, the angle is $\pi/6$ and the number out the front is $2$.   (The way the teacher knew how to get $2$ was that $\sqrt{3}^2 + 1^2 = 2^2$.)  Isaac expands on this is in his answer, and I will also write an answer explaining more what I mean, because these comment boxes are a bit frustrating to write in!  Regards,

Comment: @Matt: Thank you.  That's what I didn't understand.

Comment: @Matt: seems like a long way of doing it though--just plugging in values on the interval.

Comment: @subt13: $\frac{\pi}{6}$ is not just a random guess at what value to try—the $\sqrt{3}$ suggests something like $\frac{\pi}{6}$ or $\frac{\pi}{3}$, but a value can be found explicitly as in my answer.

Answer (score 4):

[picakhu's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17716/how-does-teacher-get-first-step/17718#17718) is the simplest way to see how it works having already arrived at $y=2\sin(x+\frac{\pi}{6})$ (use the identity there to expand this form).  In general, given $a\sin x+b\cos x$ (let's say for $a,b>0$), it is possible to arrive at a similar equivalent form:
$$\begin{align}
a\sin x+b\cos x
&=a\left(\sin x+\frac{b}{a}\cos x\right)
\\
&=a\left(\sin x+\tan\left(\arctan\frac{b}{a}\right)\cos x\right)
\\
&=a\left(\sin x+\frac{\sin\left(\arctan\frac{b}{a}\right)}{\cos\left(\arctan\frac{b}{a}\right)}\cos x\right)
\\
&=\frac{a}{\cos\left(\arctan\frac{b}{a}\right)}\left(\sin x\cos\left(\arctan\frac{b}{a}\right)+\sin\left(\arctan\frac{b}{a}\right)\cos x\right)
\\
&=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\sin\left(x+\arctan\frac{b}{a}\right).
\end{align}$$